# Fill 0's with 1's beetween two 1's (synthesizable)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Suppose we have `MSB_limit` and `LSB_limit`. These two act as two flags and **all** bits between them (even the 1's - *I think this simplifies the problem*)  must go to **1**.

Is there a synthesizable solution to this?

Example to the problem:

```
MSB_limit = 7;
LSB_limit = 2;

//Let's suppose our register is 16bits, desired output:

 0000000011111100
 ^       ^    ^ ^
 |       |    | |
15       7    2 0       //positions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned int my_reg = 1<<(MSB_limit-LSB_limit+1);  // 0000000001000000
my_reg --; // 0000000000111111
my_reg <<= LSB_limit; // 0000000011111100
```

Answer (score 3):

Easily achievable with for-loops:

SystemVerilog (IEEE 1800):

```
logic [N-1:0] my_reg;
always_comb begin
  foreach(my_reg[idx])
     my_reg[idx] = idx inside {[LSB_limit:MSB_limit]};
end
```

Verilog (IEEE 1364-2001 or greater):

```
reg [N-1:0] my_reg;
integer idx;
always @* begin
  for (idx = 0; idx < N; idx=idx+1) begin
    my_reg[idx] = (idx >= LSB_limit) && ( idx <= MSB_limit);
  end
end
```

Comment: Are `for` loops encouraged for RTL/synthesize code? Why should someone choose this style vs the other 2 answers? (pros, cons etc)

Comment: For-loops are used in RTL and are synthesizable when they can static unroll. The tend to use few gates and better timing than shift operators. Replication only works on constants (ex: LSB/MSB_limit are parameters). With dynamic limits, the for-loop allows the synthesizer to decide to use combinational decoding or shift registers. This depends on the intelligence of the synthesizer. At my work, shifting and replication is allowed with static limits. For-loops are preferred with dynamic limits. Try all the approaches and use the one that fits your requirements best.

Answer (score 3):

How about the replication operator?

```
assign out = { '0, { MSB_limit-LSB_limit+1{1'b1} }, { LSB_limit{1'b0} } };
```

Comment: This only works if MSB_limit and LSB_limit are consents.